# PHP How to add plus (+) character before double quotes and words without double quotes in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

I have below string:

```
'this is a "text field" need "to replace"'
```

And I want to add plus (+) character before every un-double quotes words and double quotes like below:

```
'+this +is +"text field" +need +"to replace"'
```

Is there any way to perform such action? I tried with `str_replace` and regex but cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: Share with us what you have tried and how it has failed.

Comment: And let know if the string can contain escaped quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this alternation based regex:

```
$re = '/"[^"]*"|\S+/m'; 
$str = 'this is a "text field" need "to replace"'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '+$0', $str);
//=> +this +is +a +"text field" +need +"to replace"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE8uH2/1)

`"[^"]*"|\S+` is the regex that matches a double quoted text OR any non-space word and replacement is `+$0` that prefixes each match with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
/(\b\w+)|("(.*?)")/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK9aF7/2)